# React Native Modal Dropdown now key/value?

Tags: react-native

Why the react-native-modal-dropdown is not a key/value property?

I'm trying to add a dropdown modal in my project, but this has a odd behavior. Are we able to handle key/value?

I have the following data that is coming from my action

```
const properties = {
    '1': 'Property 1',
    '2': 'Property 2',
    '3': 'Property 3',
};
```

I was trying to use it in my modal Dropdown

```
<ModalDropdown
    defaultIndex={this.state.CurrentPropertyID}
    options={properties}
    onSelect={(value) => this.onChangeProp(value)}
/>
```

The idea would have a function to update the CurrentPropertyID status:

```
onChangeProp(value){
   this.setState({
      CurrentPropertyID: obj
    });
```

Does it make sense?

Thanks

Comment: what is doing now? not update the current selection? CurrentPropertyID ?

Comment: It options does not accept key/value. It should be ['option 1', 'option 2', ...]

Answer (score 2):

Two kinds of option:

```
const DEMO_OPTIONS_1 = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3', 'option 4', 'option 5', 'option 6', 'option 7', 'option 8', 'option 9'];
const DEMO_OPTIONS_2 = [
  {"name": "Rex", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Mary", "age": 25},
  {"name": "John", "age": 41},
  {"name": "Jim", "age": 22},
  {"name": "Susan", "age": 52},
  {"name": "Brent", "age": 33},
  {"name": "Alex", "age": 16},
  {"name": "Ian", "age": 20},
  {"name": "Phil", "age": 24},
];

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dropdown_4_options: null,
      dropdown_4_defaultValue: 'loading...',
      dropdown_6_icon_heart: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const dropdown_6_icon = this.state.dropdown_6_icon_heart ? require('./images/heart.png') : require('./images/flower.png');
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <View style={styles.cell}>
            <ModalDropdown style={styles.dropdown_1}
                           options={DEMO_OPTIONS_1}
            />
            <ModalDropdown style={styles.dropdown_6}
                           options={DEMO_OPTIONS_1}
                           onSelect={(idx, value) => this._dropdown_6_onSelect(idx, value)}>
              <Image style={styles.dropdown_6_image}
                     source={dropdown_6_icon}
              />
            </ModalDropdown>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.cell}>
            <ModalDropdown ref="dropdown_2"
                           style={styles.dropdown_2}
                           textStyle={styles.dropdown_2_text}
                           dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown_2_dropdown}
                           options={DEMO_OPTIONS_2}
                           renderButtonText={(rowData) => this._dropdown_2_renderButtonText(rowData)}
                           renderRow={this._dropdown_2_renderRow.bind(this)}
                           renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) => this._dropdown_2_renderSeparator(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted)}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
              this.refs.dropdown_2.select(0);
            }}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>
                select Rex
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <ScrollView ref={el => this._scrollView = el}
                      style={styles.scrollView}
                      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
                      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                      scrollEventThrottle={1}>
            <Text>
              {'Scroll view example.'}
            </Text>
            <ModalDropdown ref={el => this._dropdown_3 = el}
                           style={styles.dropdown_3}
                           options={DEMO_OPTIONS_1}
                           adjustFrame={style => this._dropdown_3_adjustFrame(style)}
                           dropdownTextStyle={styles.dropdown_3_dropdownTextStyle}
                           dropdownTextHighlightStyle={styles.dropdown_3_dropdownTextHighlightStyle}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <View style={[styles.cell, {justifyContent: 'flex-end'}]}>
            <ModalDropdown style={styles.dropdown_4}
                           dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown_4_dropdown}
                           options={this.state.dropdown_4_options}
                           defaultIndex={-1}
                           defaultValue={this.state.dropdown_4_defaultValue}
                           onDropdownWillShow={this._dropdown_4_willShow.bind(this)}
                           onDropdownWillHide={this._dropdown_4_willHide.bind(this)}
                           onSelect={(idx, value) => this._dropdown_4_onSelect(idx, value)}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.cell, {justifyContent: 'flex-end'}]}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._dropdown_5_show.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>
                {'Show dropdown'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._dropdown_5_select(2)}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>
                {'Select the 3rd option'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._dropdown_5_select(-1)}>
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>
                {'Clear selection'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <ModalDropdown ref={el => this._dropdown_5 = el}
                           style={styles.dropdown_5}
                           options={['Select me to hide', `I can't be selected`, 'I can only be selected outside']}
                           defaultValue='Try the Show button above'
                           onDropdownWillShow={this._dropdown_5_willShow.bind(this)}
                           onDropdownWillHide={this._dropdown_5_willHide.bind(this)}
                           onSelect={this._dropdown_5_onSelect.bind(this)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _dropdown_2_renderButtonText(rowData) {
    const {name, age} = rowData;
    return `${name} - ${age}`;
  }

  _dropdown_2_renderRow(rowData, rowID, highlighted) {
    let icon = highlighted ? require('./images/heart.png') : require('./images/flower.png');
    let evenRow = rowID % 2;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='cornflowerblue'>
        <View style={[styles.dropdown_2_row, {backgroundColor: evenRow ? 'lemonchiffon' : 'white'}]}>
          <Image style={styles.dropdown_2_image}
                 mode='stretch'
                 source={icon}
          />
          <Text style={[styles.dropdown_2_row_text, highlighted && {color: 'mediumaquamarine'}]}>
            {`${rowData.name} (${rowData.age})`}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  _dropdown_2_renderSeparator(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) {
    if (rowID == DEMO_OPTIONS_1.length - 1) return;
    let key = `spr_${rowID}`;
    return (<View style={styles.dropdown_2_separator}
                  key={key}
    />);
  }

  _dropdown_3_adjustFrame(style) {
    console.log(`frameStyle={width:${style.width}, height:${style.height}, top:${style.top}, left:${style.left}, right:${style.right}}`);
    style.top -= 15;
    style.left += 150;
    return style;
  }

  _dropdown_4_willShow() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
      dropdown_4_options: DEMO_OPTIONS_1,
      dropdown_4_defaultValue: 'loaded',
    }), 2000);
  }

  _dropdown_4_willHide() {
    this.setState({
      dropdown_4_options: null,
      dropdown_4_defaultValue: 'loading',
    });
  }

  _dropdown_4_onSelect(idx, value) {
    // BUG: alert in a modal will auto dismiss and causes crash after reload and touch. @sohobloo 2016-12-1
    //alert(`idx=${idx}, value='${value}'`);
    console.debug(`idx=${idx}, value='${value}'`);
  }

  _dropdown_5_show() {
    this._dropdown_5 && this._dropdown_5.show();
  }

  _dropdown_5_select(idx) {
    this._dropdown_5 && this._dropdown_5.select(idx);
  }

  _dropdown_5_willShow() {
    return false;
  }

  _dropdown_5_willHide() {
    let idx = this._dropdown_5_idx;
    this._dropdown_5_idx = undefined;
    return idx == 0;
  }

  _dropdown_5_onSelect(idx, value) {
    this._dropdown_5_idx = idx;
    if (this._dropdown_5_idx != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  _dropdown_6_onSelect(idx, value) {
    this.setState({
      dropdown_6_icon_heart: !this.state.dropdown_6_icon_heart,
    })
  }
}
```